# Keyframed rigid body animation won't work

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a scene with a passive rigid body element (the floor of my scene) and an *active* rigid body element (the letter "P"). But the entirety of the scene includes multiple camera passes (each camera bound to markers in the timeline). After the final pass, I want the "P" letter to be affected by gravity.

Per my earlier research, I keyframed the Rigid Body - Settings attributes: Dynamic & Animated. The mesh is set as Animated until keyframe 2701, when it is set as Dynamic. At that point, I expect the "P" mesh to fall over. It does not. I don't understand why not.

Additional detail: The scale on both letters and the scene-floor and two meshes are set to 1.

Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks for your attention.

[My Blend if you have the time to look...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hR-Ms7ZczKv0NWkAUTKyMjnspbWxSD6X/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work but if you go in the Properties panel > Scene > Cach > Bake (don't forget to put the Simulation End at 310), it seems to work. Also I think it's better to put the origin of the object (P letter) at its geometry. I hope someone will find why it doesn't work without bake though...

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice. Not baking the sim was, indeed, the problem. With regard the object model at geometry, I am using the 3D cursor to adjust the origins since I failed to do that at the outset.